# Cannot add or update software in software center,

Tags: software-center

Having trouble with software center. it says *Canceling* but does nothing.

I get

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I tried a hard reboot and the problem still exists.   Thanks for your help

Comment: No solution yet....Help...I could spend the two hours formatting and rebuilding the system and data but I donwanna

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sudo killall apt-get
```

if this doesn't work, try to manually remove the lock:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ still locked by another process.  How can I find that process and kill it?
jess@jess-OptiPlex-GX260:~$ 
rrrggg. its gonna get a wipe if it does not beave

Comment: I still am having issues with this, and software center, despite removing the cache, is still hung up says searching.  Anyone with any ideas?  Running out of paticence.

Comment: so try those commands: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` then 
`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Finally solved.  Thanks Hakeem.  I finally got it using the first.I still had locked file issues, so I rm'ed each locked file one at a time from the top and ran configure - a option until it rebuilt each file, finally asking if I wanted grub to create something.  I said yes.  then did the update.  At this point, I was still showing waiting under the  software center.  I died a reboot, and everything appears clear now.  Thanks.